# how to serve ionic sqlite database app in browser

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

When I am running **ionic** app with sqlite database in **browser** using ionic serve browser display error as **cordova_not_available**.
ionic 3.9.2

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is meant to work on mobile phone and not in the browser.It is mandatory to install SQLite plugin to make use of the SQLite DB on your phone.

To install SQLite plugin use the below command:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git
```

To know more about how to use sqlite in ionic frame work check the below video
[SQLite Video](https://youtu.be/lxrsT4n86YI)

Comment: So always i have to test with emulator or real device

Comment: @ShehanKarunarathne if u don't install any cordova plugins you can test in our browser itself else you have to do it in emulator or in real device only